# Set description for programmatically generated assembly in C#

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

How can I set assembly description?

I'm generating assembly programmatically

```
CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#").CompileAssemblyFromFile(parameters, files);
```

But i don't know where are assembly properties. is there any way to set these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CompileAssemblyFromFile` takes an array of files. Include `AssemblyInfo.cs` file with required attributes, like

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("My Assembly Name")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: Guid("594dd732-1e7d-4981-ada3-efb341e5f918")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
```

`AssemblyInfo.cs` is a file, which added by `Visual Studio` to any project by default. You can name it whatever you want, but i suggest to stick with this convention.

Comment: I've already figured it out. I created question too eraly, but thx.

Comment: Not at all. Sometimes just stating the problem definition makes you aware of it's solution